# Can you kick a stick in NHL?

Tags: rules, ice-hockey, nhl

If a player drops his stick and a player of the opposing team kicks it away from him as he tries to reach for it, will the opposing player get penalized? A common situation would be when the goalie loses his stick. It would be good strategy for the opposing team to kick the stick away from him.

How about if a teammate kicks it towards the player who has dropped his stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the text of rule [625-a-6](http://www.usahockeyrulebook.com/page/show/1084676-rule-625-interference), your first situation is considered interference, and the player who kicks away the stick from an opponent is assessed a minor penalty.

As for teammates helping each other, this is not disallowed, and nor is there much reason to.